# KrakenD catchall path

Tags: microservices, krakend

I have two paths in KrakenD config: /city/toronto and /city/vancouver. I want to create another path /city/other that would catch every other city that would be provided.

I know at first glance one would say: make the city a path parameter or one would even say make the city a query parameter. I have considered these options and they are not viable.

Is there a way in Krakend To define a catchall or fallback endpoint?  I though wildcard could allow me to do this but I am not seeing how this would work.

Answer (score 0):

In earlier versions of KrakenD this was not possible, but since 1.4 you can use routes that before were considered to be conflicting. The following example does exactly what you are expecting. Run with the `-d` flag:

`krakend run -d -c krakend.json` where the content of the JSON file is:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "endpoints": [
    {
      "endpoint": "/city/vancouver",
      "backend": [
        {
          "url_pattern": "/__debug/vancouver",
          "host": [
            "http://localhost:8080"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
       "endpoint": "/city/toronto",
       "backend": [
         {
           "url_pattern": "/__debug/toronto",
           "host": [
             "http://localhost:8080"
           ]
         }
       ]
     },
    {
      "endpoint": "/city/{other}",
      "backend": [
        {
          "url_pattern": "/__debug/catchall",
          "host": [
            "http://localhost:8080"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```